# Rewrite url using htaccess on php sites

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I'm creating an htaccess to rewrite an URL. It's working fine. My code is the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*)/ ?site=$1
```

Original URL :

```
/domain/sites/admin/index.php?site=site1
```

Output URL:

```
/domain/sites/admin/index/site1
```

But I need the URL to be like this

```
/domain/sites/site1/admin
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^domain/sites/(.*)/admin$ /domain/sites/admin/index.php?site=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Your right, haven't done rewrite rules in ages...

Answer (score 0):

To understand: `/domain/sites/admin/index/site1` is the url and the path is `/domain/sites/admin/index.php?site=site1` so you need `/domain/sites/site1/admin` to path to `/domain/sites/admin/index.php?site=site1`?

If so:
`RewriteRule site/(.*)/admin /sites/admin/index.php?site=$1`

I think...

Comment: it's not working. the result is object not found

Comment: `RewriteRule sites/(.*)/admin` Sorry forgot the 's'